# How can I update AD users using PowerShell and CSV import?

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I'm trying to use this powershell script to update AD users.  Ideally I'll be updating a bunch of attributes, but for now I'm just trying to get it to update the department just so I get tell if it's working.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$dataSource=import-csv "c:\ADupdate.csv"
foreach($dataRecord in $datasource) {
$employeeID=$dataRecord.employeeID

# List of attributes to update
$department=$dataRecord.department

Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" -Identity $employeeID -Properties department | Set-ADUser -Replace @{department=$department}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own problem.  Here is what I ended up  using if anyone else is interested... though I'm using a lot of attributes.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory  

$users = Import-Csv -Path c:\update.csv

foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-ADUser -Filter "employeeID -eq '$($user.employeeID)'" -Properties * -SearchBase "ou=Test,ou=OurUsers,ou=Logins,dc=domain,dc=com" |
Set-ADUser -employeeNumber $($user.employeeNumber) -department $($user.department) -title $($user.title) -office $($user.office) -streetAddress $($user.streetAddress) -City $($user.City) -state $($user.state) -postalCode $($user.postalCode) -OfficePhone $($user.OfficePhone) -mobile $($user.mobile) -Fax $($user.Fax) -replace @{"extensionAttribute1"=$user.extensionAttribute1; "extensionAttribute2"=$user.extensionAttribute2; "extensionAttribute3"=$user.extensionAttribute3}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `-Properties *` if you are not going to be using _all_ of the properties. `-Properties "title","department","streetAddress",etc.` would be more efficient. In fact in your case you don't need it at all since you values are fed by CSV